# The column 'Date Offset' in table 'Date' has invalid bindings specified

Tags: ssas, tabular-model, ssas-2016

I'm trying to deploy a tabular model to a server using the "Analysis Services Deployment Wizard".

When attempting to deploy,I get the below error.

> The JSON DDL request failed with the following error: Failed to execute XMLA. Error returned: 'The column 'Date Offset' in table 'Date' has invalid bindings specified.

The column in question uses the below calculation, which was found [here](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2013/01/24/building-relative-date-reports-in-powerpivot/)

```
INT([Date] - TODAY())
```

What should I look for in order to resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in this case was that I was trying to replace an existing column also named 'Date Offset' - this was not a calculated column, but taken from the source table.

Resolution was to do the deployment in 2 phases, first remove the old column, then deploy again to add the new calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by deleting the cube completely off of the server before doing another deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Tried different methods like renaming column and removed filters applied, didn't solved this issue.
At the end this issue fixed by just deleting existing cube and redeployed

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I remove duplicated columns and the error persisted.

It only worked when I did **delete model in azure** --> analysis services.

Answer (score 0):

So I had this error and I was able to resolve it by deleting the column from the `model.bim`. You have to be  careful and make a copy of the `model.bim` before you start making changes.
Then I created the calculated column and gave it a new name and it worked fine.

I hope my answer helps others.